# I need help converting strings into camelCase with multiple "_" using loop

Tags: java, string, loops, camelcasing

My code doesnt convert ex. dog_cat_dog into dogCatDog. The out put of my code is dogCat_dog. Trying to make a loop that doesn't stop at the first "_":

```
public String underscoreToCamel(String textToConvert) {
   int index_= textToConvert.indexOf("_",0);
   String camelCase="";
   String upperCase = "";
   String lowerCase="";
   for (int i=0; i < textToConvert.length(); i++){
     if(i==index_){
       upperCase= (textToConvert.charAt(index_+1)+upperCase).toUpperCase();
       upperCase= upperCase+ textToConvert.substring(index_+2);
       
     }
     else{
       lowerCase=textToConvert.substring(0,index_);
     }
     camelCase=lowerCase+upperCase;
     

   }
     
        return camelCase;
   }
```

Comment: Share code as text not as image please

Comment: images are hard to debug, please share your code in a [mre] that illustrates the issue you are having

Comment: Would you agree to regular expression to do a replacement ? That would be very easy

Comment: @azro regular expression makes the job of the code easy, but it is not without a penalty. The penalty is that, in general, regex solutions are harder to maintain. Maintainability is a more costly attribute in relation to initial development cost. So, most likely, in the real world a regex solution will be impractical.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following: make the method `static`, it does not use any class state. Then instantiate a `StringBuilder` with the passed in value, because that is *mutable*. Then iterate the `StringBuilder`. If the current character is underscore, delete the current character, then replace the now current character with its upper case equivalent. Like,

```
public static String underscoreToCamel(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) == '_') {
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            char ch = Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(i));
            sb.setCharAt(i, ch);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I tested like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(underscoreToCamel("dog_cat_dog"));
}
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
dogCatDog
```

Comment: This is the best solution! The trick here is use the capabilities of `StringBuilder` to do String manipulation. It is much easier than using the native `String` methods. I was going to post a similar answer. No need for that now. One minor suggestion, convert the character at index 0 to lower case in case the character is upper case. In the code I was going to post, I had that test case in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` on '_' then rebuild.

```
public static String underscoreToCamel(String textToConvert) {
    String [] words = textToConvert.split("_");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(words[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0)));
        sb.append(words[i].substring(1));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy way to solve this is to first consider the base cases, then tackle the other cases

```
public static String underscoreToCamel(String textToConvert){

    //Initialize the return value
    String toReturn = "";

    if (textToConvert == null){
        //Base Case 1: null value, so just return an empty string
        return "";
    } else if (textToConvert.indexOf("_") == -1) {
        //Base Case 2: string without underscore, so just return that string
        return textToConvert;
    } else {
        //Primary Case:

        //Find index of underscore
        int underscore = textToConvert.indexOf("_");

        //Append everything before the underscore to the return string
        toReturn += textToConvert.substring(0, underscore);

        //Append the uppercase of the first letter after the underscore
        toReturn += textToConvert.substring(underscore+1, underscore+2).toUpperCase();

        //Append the rest of the textToConvert, passing it recursively to this function
        toReturn += underscoreToCamel(textToConvert.substring(underscore+2));
    }

    //Final return value
    return toReturn;
}
```